# Resizing Pool to 1 has been disabled by default on Ceph Pacific stable 6.0

Tags: ceph

I implemented Ceph Pacific Stable 6.0 with Ceph-Ansible on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
but when I want to change size of my pool from 3 to 1 with following command:

```
sudo ceph -n client.admin --keyring=/etc/ceph/ceph.client.admin.keyring osd pool set cephfs_data size 1
```

I get following error:

> Error EPERM: configuring pool size as 1 is disabled by default.

Comment: can you share the log?

Comment: Error EPERM: configuring pool size as 1 is disabled by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add the following option under section `[global]` in `ceph.conf`:

```
mon_allow_pool_size_one = true
```

2. Restart the monitor service

Answer (score 4):

For those working with Quincy (17.2.3) you can do:

```
$ ceph config set global  mon_allow_pool_size_one true
$ ceph osd pool set data_pool min_size 1
$ ceph osd pool set data_pool size 1 --yes-i-really-mean-it
```

Comment: **Note:** After change pool size to 1, cluster will be to warning mode (for replica size). To eliminate or mute this warn you should run this command. `ceph health mute POOL_NO_REDUNDANCY`